# Is there a way to approximate $y=-W(-e^{-x-1})$ for large value of x? (W is the lambert's function)

Tags: approximation, lambert-w

I was working on a problem about carnot heat pump and came across this equation $y=-W(-e^{-x-1})$ and when i plotted it, it seems to me that for large value of x it started becoming linear so i was wondering if there is a way I could approximate this for large value of x.[dotted line represents $y=x+5$ and the black line represent $y=-W(-e^{-x-1})$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSKyc.png)

I've tried some approximation already. I tried using the lagrange inversion theorem to expand the Lambert's function and after some approximation i ended up with $y=e^{-x-1}(e^{-x-1}+1)$, then after i've [plotted it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YyR3.png)
(dotted line is after the approximation) it seems like it's working for only small values of y.

Comment: You should specify what $W$ is. [Lambert's W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)?

Comment: yes, thanks for the advice.

Comment: $\newcommand{\W}{\mathfrak{W}}$It is known that for $|x|<1/e$: $$\W(x)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-n)^{n-1}}{n!}x^n$$So, for $|-e^{-x-1}|<1/e$, i.e. for $e^{x+1}>e,\,x>0$: $$-\W(-e^{-x-1})=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!}e^{-n(x+1)}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chatzigeorgiou proved bounds on the exact expression you have in 2013: for $x>0$
$$1+\sqrt{2x}+\frac23x<-W_{-1}(-e^{-x-1})<1+\sqrt{2x}+x$$
Tighter upper bounds are possible if $x$ is known to be bounded; if $x<1$, $\frac34x$ can replace $x$ in the upper bound.

Another approximation is given in the first section of the paper. Let $a=0.3205$, then
$$-W_{-1}(-e^{-x-1})\approx1+x+\frac2a\left(1-\frac1{1+a\sqrt{x/2}}\right)$$

---

Ioannis Chatzigeorgiou (2013), "[Bounds on the Lambert function and their Application to the Outage Analysis of User Cooperation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.04895)", *IEEE Communications Letters* **17** (8), pp. 1505–1508

Comment: Thanks, it helps alot.